# CloudKit - "Invalid bundle ID for container"

Tags: swift, cloudkit, xcode9beta6

**I've just create a project in Xcode 9 beta 6 and add this code:**

```
let privateDB = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
let greatID = CKRecordID(recordName: "GreatPlace")
let place = CKRecord(recordType: "Place", recordID: greatID)

privateDB.save(place) { (record, error) in
        if error != nil {
            let er = (error as! CKError).errorUserInfo
            print("Error: \n")
            print("CKErrorDescription: \(er["CKErrorDescription"]!)\n")
            print("ContainerID: \(er["ContainerID"]!)\n")
            print("NSDebugDescription: \(er["NSDebugDescription"]!)\n")
            print("NSUnderlyingError: \(er["NSUnderlyingError"]!)\n")
            print("NSLocalizedDescription: \(er["NSLocalizedDescription"]!)\n")
            print("ServerErrorDescription: \(er["ServerErrorDescription"]!)\n")
        }
        if record != nil {
            print("record: \(record!)")
        }
 }
```

**and add this capabilities:**

[image]

**and when I run the code I receive this error message:**

[image]

**What I am doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**There was a bug causing some associations to be missed. That bug has been fixed and we automatically fixed the container/app associations that were broken during that time.**

If for some reason you still need to redo an association you can either use the Capabilities pane in Xcode or use developer.apple.com -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> App IDs -> pick the ID -> Edit -> Edit under iCloud -> check the box for the container to disassociate, save, then re-associate.

If you're still stuck please email cloudkit[at]apple.com

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your answer. Actually, every new project I tried to create using CloudKit has the same problem. What should I do ? Send only the bundle ID and Container ID I'm currently working on ? Regards !

Comment: I have the same error, I tried your solution but it doesn't work. Just nothing changed :(

Comment: Just encountered the same issue with Xcode 12.5. Playing with the Capabilities pane in Xcode didn't help, but the 2nd solution (reassociating via developer.apple.com) did. Of course I had to regenerate the provisioning profiles for the app after editing the App ID.

Comment: I've set up iCloud on a few projects without seeing this issue. However I recently encountered it.

I noticed a "iCloud Container Assignment" button; the container I set up in Xcode was not associated there.

Comment: After many frustrating hours I came to this answer. What worked for me is: 1. deselect the container on Xcode, 2. deselect container on developer.apple.com (and save), 3. select container again on website, 4. regenerate profiles and finally 5. select container on Xcode.

Comment: @vauxhall thanks for your solution, this worked! Dave, you and the team might want to check this.

Comment: @vauxhall's solution worked for me, but since I am having Xcode manage signing, I had to turn off "Automatically Manage Signing", then follow the steps, and then turn it back on, which seemed to re-created the auto-generated profile.

Comment: @coping for me it worked even after the auto-generate profile. Seems like after it manages to associate it continues to do so after re-creations..

Comment: For me just resetting the iCloud capability was not enough. But everything worked after I removed the entire App ID (it was managed by XCode)

Comment: Some years later I just had this issue with Xcode 13

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Dave Browning, this is based on his answer.

Following worked for me:

###### Check the container id

- Check the container id used for initialisation of `CKContainer`
- Note: If you are using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` we wouldn't be using the container id directly would be picked automatically from the entitlements file.

##### Try to disable and enable iCloud on the App ID

#### Disable and Enable iCloud on App ID

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com and sign in
2. Select `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles`
3. Select `Identifiers` (App IDs)
4. Edit App ID for the app
5. Uncheck iCloud
6. Save
7. Check iCloud
8. Quit Xcode and Clear DerivedData
9. Run app

Comment: This worked. The problem was on Certificates side. And automatic Xcode sign didn't work, since I'm not the admin in the team.

Answer (score 0):

My friend and I are having the same issue. We made 2 different projects and both of them had the same error message "Invalid bundle ID for container" which is [CKError case 10](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckerror.code/1514887-permissionfailure) .

We are calling our fetch function to get the default "Users" record in the viewDidLoad.

```
func fetchWorkoutCompleted(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void = { _ in }) {
    cloudKitManager.fetchRecord(ofType: "Users", sortDescriptors: nil) { (records, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(error)
            return
        }
        guard let records = records else { completion(nil); return }
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think it could be an environment problem?

Comment: Yeah, it might have something to do with the Apple's Keynote. I have several small cloudKit projects from the past that are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xamarin.IOS, I had to select manual provisioning rather than automatic provisioning in the info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. what worked for me was changing the iCloud group name.

- Before it was something like this: `iCloud.com.companyName.appName.randomString`
- After changing to: `iCloud.com.companyName.randomString` it started working and synchronising.

If after adding the new container it's red press the refresh button(from under the groups) and try a clean install on your phone and it should work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to delete the app from the device, and initialize it again. Then it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is that for creating a container I use `CKContainer.default()`. I have two different bundle identifier (debug and release) and `CKContainer.default()` will take the CK container identifier to be the same as the bundle identifier of the app. When I change for creating a container to use `CKContainer(identifier: “my_cloudkit_identifier”)` I could use the same CK container for the debug and release.